# Transfer jsfiddle to dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, html, css, dreamweaver, jsfiddle

I give. I can't seem to get the jsfiddle code to work when I transfer it to dreamweaver? I must be missing something simple?? It works fine in jsfiddle. I added the ready function as opposed to the onload, but it still is not working.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {

      var h1 = $('div#greeting h1');

      h1.hide().contents().each(function() {
        var words;
        if (this.nodeType === 3) {
          words = this.data.split(/\s+/).map(function(w) {
            return '<span>' + w + '</span>';
          }).join('');
          $(this).replaceWith(words);
        } else if (this.nodeType === 1) {
          $(this).html($(this).html().split(/\s+/).map(function(w) {
            return '<span>' + w + '</span>';
          }).join(''));
        }
      });

      h1.find('span').hide().each(function() {
        if (!$.trim(this.innerHTML)) {
          $(this).remove();
        }
      });

      $('#start').on('click', function() {
        h1.show().find('span').each(function(i, e) {
          h1.queue(function(next) {
            $.when($(e).fadeIn(150).fadeOut(150)).done(next);
          });
        });
      });
      $('#stop').on('click', function() {
        h1.finish();
      });
      $('#reset').on('click', function() {
        h1.finish();
      });
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #E38E34;
  background-color: #FFE7BF;
  height: 150px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
#title {
  margin: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E38E34;
  color: #C46908;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#message {
  margin: 5px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

  <title>TedsCode</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="speedread.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box" />
  <div id="title"><span id="name">Title</span> 
  </div>
  <div id="message" />
  <div id="greeting" />
  <input type="button" value="Read" id="start" />
  <input type="button" value="Stop" id="stop" />
  <input type="button" value="Reset" id="reset" />
  <h1><center>This is a test to see if this script displays one word at a time and functions correctly.</center></h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hava a syntax error in js.

I comment on something: add "});" to js, and remove redundant reference of jquery.

Code snippet works now

Comment: Wow, dreamweaver should have showed the error. Thank you, it's working great. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can see two things:
1-Why are you using two version of jquery at the same time 1.9.1 and 2.1.0?
2-In the code you paste, the $("document").ready(function() {
isn't properly closed

Are you receiving any error in the console or the network ?

Comment: Wow, it was not showing an error in dreamweaver, amazing how simple it can be. Thank you.